# Почему авто-преобразование int в char возможно, а long в char нет?

Tags: java, преобразование, преобразование-типов, syntax

Почему авто-преобразование int в char возможно, а long в char нет? В чём логика?

```
    final int v4 = 1;
    final long v5 = 1;

    char a1 = v4;
    char a2 = v5; // Ошибка: "Несоответствие типов: невозможно преобразовать long в char"
```

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev должно бы, а проверил пример ТС и на v4 почему-то не вылетает ошибка https://ideone.com/jpVI49   Может дело в `final`?

Comment: Хмм... Объявление переменной финальной изменяет поведение.

Comment: Всё, я понял. И для работы с `char` и для работы с `int` используются опкоды, оперирующие 32-битными значениями. Когда переменная помечается финальной, компилятор применяет свёртку констант и получается `char a1 = 1`. Но для `long` это не срабатывает потому, что опкод `lconst_1` равносилен 64-битной единице - `1L`.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, Этим можно обосновать то, что long **никогда** не авто-преобразовываться **в нижестоящие**  по диапазонам типы (хотя литералы и константы int, short, byte в случаи подходящего значения могут)?

Comment: @KenyValisamin да.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, в ответе ниже говорится, что ваша версия неверная, потому что: "В Java тип char - лишь 16 бит". Можно услышать ваше мнение на этот счёт?

Comment: @KenyValisamin я вполне могу ошибаться. А может и Ростислав. Вам стоит  самостоятельно проверить в какой байткод компилируется инструкция `char a1 = v4` и сверить по [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html) разрядность операндов. Так же полезно будет спросить у Ростислава ссылки на те части JLS, которые объясняют "логику компилятора".

Answer (score 2):

Потому что локальные `final int` и `final long` становятся литералами разных типов, не все из которых подходят для инициализации переменной типа `char`. Никакого авто-преобразование `int` в `char` здесь нет. Это можно проиллюстрировать на следующем примере:

```
    char a = ' ';       // можно, символьный литерал
    char b = 32;        // можно, десятичный литерал
    char c = 040;       // можно, восьмеричный литерал
    char d = 0x20;      // можно, шестнадцатиричный литерал
    char e = 3200000;   // нельзя, выход за границы числовых значений char 0..65535
    char f = 32L;       // нельзя, литерал несовместимого типа
```

Комментарий выше, об использовании 32-х битных опкодов для манипуляций с `char`, неверен. В Java тип `char` - лишь 16 бит. Фактически это беззнаковая версия `short`, аналог `unsigned short` в языках C/C++.

Comment: ну так если не апкоды, то почему (какая логика) литерал long не подходит? Я спрашивал про объяснение, а не про факт.

Comment: Это логика компилятора. В Java нет отдельных целых типов литералов для инициализации `byte`, `short` и `char`, поэтому инициализировать переменные этих типов можно обычными целыми литералами, значения которых не выходят за соответствующие границы. Эта проверка происходит во время компиляции. Теоритечески можно было бы делать так же (проверять границы значений) и с long литералами, при инициализации менее разрядных целых переменных, но авторы языка это запретили. Наверное это некое наследие из C, где `int` обязан быть машинным словом, а `long` может быть больше.

Comment: ой нелогично: int-литерал проверить может, что подходит, а long - сделаем как в с, такую мелочь как в c..., для кого??? для чего??? Апкоды правдоподобнее.

Comment: @KenyValisamin Ну а в C/C++ разве есть специальные суффиксы к литералам для `byte`, `short` и `int`? К тому же `long` в Java можно инициализировать и обычным целым литералом, без суффикса, если его значение не выходит за границы `int`. Компилятор сам добавит этот суффикс в байткод. Значит компилятор мог бы компилировать и наоборот - убирать этот суффикс там, где он не нужен. Но он так не делает - потому что так решили разработчики языка, а не потому это невозможно. Они просто унаследовали это из C/C++.

Comment: Я вот сейчас мог бы понять смысл этого так: у int нет суффикса, убрать ничего не надо, а у long есть, значит надо лишнее действие; решили не тратится, не выгодно и т. д. – унаследовали хорошую(!) логику из C/C++. /// Но вы же сами пишете: "Компилятор сам добавит этот суффикс в байткод". У любого типа есть суффиксы, и всегда надо ими оперировать. "просто унаследовали" – так бывает в этом мире??? просто так, ни для кого, без логики, без выгоды, без объяснения, без удобства...

Comment: не бывает. Поэтому я и спрашиваю причину, за исключением "просто так". Хотя бы что-то типа (пример): в начале у разработчиков руки не дошли, потом для обратной совместимости – уже логично.

Comment: @KenyValisamin Причина очевидна - наследие C/C++. Точно так же можно долго выяснять почему индексы массивов в Java начинаются с нуля, а не с единицы, как например в Pascal или почему они не могут быть отрицательными, как в Phyton. Это тоже наследие C, где массив реализован на уровне препроцессора, как адресная арифметика, и поэтому вместо `a[3] = 7;` можно написать `3[a] = 7;` и это будет работать точно так же. В Java никакой адресной арифметике нет, а наследие C/C++ осталось.